# Make marker color and shape according to different categorical variables

Tags: python, seaborn, lmplot

I need to generate a scatter plot, where multiple categorical variables can be represented by color and shape of the scatters. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animals':pd.Series(['tiger','cheetah','lion','giraffe','elephant','gorilla']),
               'weight': pd.Series([200,120,240,240,400,300]),
               'meal': pd.Series([20,10,40,15,40,30]),
               'region': pd.Categorical(["Asian","American","African","African",'Asian','American']),
              'gender': pd.Categorical(["female","female","male","female",'male','male']),
              'group': pd.Series([True, False, False, True, True, True])})

sns.lmplot(data = df, x = 'weight', y = 'meal', hue = 'region', palette = 'Dark2',
       fit_reg = False, scatter_kws={"s": 20}, size = 4)
```

This will create a plot, where the region is represented by different colors.
But I also need to represent the gender, in different shapes. So the color shows the region and the shape shows the gender.
Is there a way to achieve this? thanks for any suggestion!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to simply pass a list of markers in your call to [`sns.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'animals':pd.Series(['tiger','cheetah','lion','giraffe','elephant','gorilla']),
               'weight': pd.Series([200,120,240,240,400,300]),
               'meal': pd.Series([20,10,40,15,40,30]),
               'region': pd.Categorical(["Asian","American","African","African",'Asian','American']),
              'gender': pd.Categorical(["female","female","male","female",'male','male']),
              'group': pd.Series([True, False, False, True, True, True])})

sns.lmplot(data = df, x = 'weight', y = 'meal', hue = 'region', palette = 'Dark2',
       fit_reg = False, scatter_kws={"s": 20}, size = 4, markers=["o","+","x"])

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: You got me. :)  I'll delete.  +1

Comment: Thanks DavidG and Scott. This way, the same variable is represented by both color and shape. Is there a way to represent one variable, eg region,  in color and a different variable, eg gender, in shape? Thanks

Comment: Hi @berry14 , have you solved your question? may you share the script, please?